# How to change the import path in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated the SDK in my Eclipse , Now I can't import the class files in my project. How can I see the path of import and how to change it. After updating the SDK my app version is changed to android 19 from android 17, But even though all the class files are available but still the errors are coming.

Comment: Please [update your ADT version](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+update+adt+plugin+eclipse&oq=how+to+update+adt&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.11025j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) also, May be this will resolve your problem

Comment: check the error in problems tab in your Eclipse.

Comment: What kind of errors you are getting post screen shot or something..